# Child component: can't convert undefined to object, how to fix?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a form from an underlying data model. The data is in an Object (`Member`), some of whose properties are also Objects (i.e., sub-objects). I'm trying to render the sub-objects in a child view. I'm able to render the Member properties at the parent level, but when I get to the sub-objects/child view, I get console errors (`ERROR TypeError: "can't convert undefined to object"`) and the child view doesn't render at all.

I'm pretty sure the error occurs at `objKeys = Object.keys(this.objEnroll);` and in initializing my Member Object I've tried to make sure that all the properties are initialized so that nothing is undefined.

"Member" Object:

```
export class Member {

    constructor(
        private userName: string ="",
        private password: string = "",
        private uId: number = 0,
        private idData: NameId = {
            "familyName": {"Family Name: ": ''}, 
            "givenName":{"Given Name(s): ": ''}, 
            "middleName":{"Middle Name(s): ": ''}
        },
}

export interface NameId {
    "familyName": {"Family Name: ": string},
    "givenName": {"Given Name(s): ": string},
    "middleName": {"Middle Name(s): ": string}
}
```

Main Form:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  . . .
  <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let key of memberKeys">
      <td>{{key}}</td>
      <ng-container *ngIf="topLevel(member[key]); else subTable">
        <td><input type="text" name="{{key}}" placeholder="Enter {{key}} Here" formControlName="{{key}}"/></td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-template #subTable>
        <app-sub-enroll-form [objEnroll]="member[key]"></app-sub-enroll-form> 
      </ng-template>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Main Form Component:

```
export class EnrollFormComponent implements OnInit {
  formControls = {};
  form: FormGroup;
  @Input() member: Member = new Member("");
  memberKeys = Object.keys(this.member);

  constructor(private templateVal: TemplateValidationService ) {  }

topLevel(s: any): boolean {
  return (this.templateVal.primType(s)) ?  true : false ;
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.memberKeys.forEach((key) => {
    let validators = [];
    this.templateVal.handleValidation(key, validators);
    this.formControls[key] = new FormControl(this.member[key], validators);
  })
  this.form = new FormGroup(this.formControls);
  }
}
```

Sub Form Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sub-enroll-form',
  templateUrl: './sub-enroll-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sub-enroll-form.component.css']
})
export class SubEnrollFormComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() objEnroll : NameId | EmailData | PhoneData | AddressData;
\\ *** I BELIEVE THE NEXT LINE IS CREATING THE PROBLEM . . . 
objKeys = Object.keys(this.objEnroll);
form: FormGroup;
formControls = {};

  constructor(private templateVal: TemplateValidationService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.objKeys.forEach((key) => {
    let validators = [];
    this.templateVal.handleValidation(key, validators);
    this.formControls[key] = new FormControl(this.objEnroll[key], validators);
  })
  this.form = new FormGroup(this.formControls);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just try moving the line `objKeys = Object.keys(this.objEnroll);` as the first line in ngOnInit of SubEnrollFormComponent. I believe the @Input directive values are available by the time angular executes OnInit lifecycle hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input variables are not available during the construction. Accessing input properties should be done in the [OnInit Lifecycle](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#oninit).

To solve your problem simply move `objKeys = Object.keys(this.objEnroll);` into the  `ngOnInit` method:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.objKeys = Object.keys(this.objEnroll);
  this.objKeys.forEach((key) => {
    let validators = [];
    this.templateVal.handleValidation(key, validators);
    this.formControls[key] = new FormControl(this.objEnroll[key], validators);
  })
  this.form = new FormGroup(this.formControls);
  }
}
```